# How to time a 2001 Saturn 2.2liter DOHC?

Tags: engine, saturn, timing

I had a weird problem. Drove the car two minutes up the street to a gas station to get air in the tires. It is literally two minutes. Car ran fine. No problem. I shut it off. Got out to pump the tires. That took a few minutes. Climb back in turned it over and it is now sputtering and making a ticking/slapping sound. Come to find out it jumped time. The chain was loose enough to slap the top chain guard. Would love to know what would cause this. So I replaced the chain and put back together. I did the timing from a video on YouTube. Must have got it wrong because all the car will do is whine wen turning the key. It starts to backfire for a split second at the keys first turn then just whines. CAN ANYONE HELP ME WITH THE TIMING MARKS and HOW TO TIME IT CORRECTLY.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

When you shut off the car the cams can rotate counterclockwise due to spring tension. This compresses the tensioner and if there's too much play in the chain it jumps timing.

When you installed the chain, there should be three color marks on the chain that correspond to a mark on each gear. On the cam gears there are diamond marks, on the crank it's just a dot IIRC. The diamond marks on the cams should be facing away from each other 45° from 12 o'clock. I think the crank mark is slightly offset to the right side bottom ~5 o'clock with the woodruff key at 12 o'clock.

If you didn't, install new chain guides and a new tensioner. If you did replace the tensioner they come in a locked position. You need to use something that won't damage the chain to unlock the tensioner. You place it against the chain on the tension side and push down and in. The tensioner has to move at least 2mm before it releases.

When you're done rotate the engine by hand to check for binding. Check to make sure the timing marks line up. They won't be lined up with the color marks on the chain. So you need to do this by eye or first measuring the angle.